# Oracle Home path for 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I had 11g previously installed and now I have installed 12c. Have not uninstalled 11g.

The environment variable `'path'` is set to `'bin'` of 12c and oracle home is pointing to home i.e `'11.2.0\server'`, of 11g.

It works but I want the Oracle_Home variable to be set to home of 12c. I do not find the path to server of 12c even after much research.

What is the path to `'home'` of 12c?

Comment: tech_logman : Please check my answer and let me know if it helped

Answer (score 2):

You said,

> "The environment variable 'path' is set to 'bin' of 12c"

It should be a path that looks something like

`C:\app\oracle_account\product\12.1.0\somefolder\bin` in *windows*
*or*
    `\u01\app\oracle\12.1.0\somefolder\bin` in *Unix/Linux*

So, your Oracle 12c home should be

`C:\app\oracle_account\product\12.1.0\somefolder` *or*

```
\u01\app\oracle\12.1.0\somefolder\
```

Now, in windows, check the registry entry ( regedit )

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_HOME_NAME
```

It should be set to the new oracle home discussed above otherwise change it or go to environment variables and set the `ORACLE_HOME` value.

Now, your `PATH` can be set using `set PATH=%ORACLE_HOME%\bin;%PATH%` to point to the correct bin directory.

For Unix, Linux you could `export` them correctly in the environment which you use to connect to the database.

```
export ORACLE_HOME='\u01\app\oracle\12.1.0\somefolder'
```

Comment: Found bin folder in /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1